# Forcing alignment of div to bottom right of page using flex

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

We're using flexbox in our Angular 2 app but I'm running into an issue where, while once data is loaded the div containing pagination components appears below the data, in the second or so where the data is still loading the pagination components float to the top of the screen. I want to lock the position of the pagination components so a user doesn't see that movement. This is the css for the pagination component:

```
.pagination {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

What can I add to force this to position at the bottom of the page so it doesn't float to the top before the data loads? When I tried adding `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0` it overrode other flex positioning and aligned left, when it should be right. So I want to use flex to do this - not standard css.

So, to summarize, I need this to force align right, AND align bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.pagination {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  align-content: flex-end;
}
```

---

An initial setting of a flex container is `flex-direction: row`. This means that the *main axis* is horizontal and `justify-content` – which only works on the main axis – will align flex items horizontally.

For vertical alignment in a row-direction container use `align-items` (for a single line container, i.e., `nowrap`) and/or `align-content` (for a multiline container, i.e., `wrap`)

Comment: Great. Thanks, Michael.